# Error when using "#Bool" in the route

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am a beginner in yesod.
I am trying to add a piece "/designmulti/key/#Int/name/#String/finished/#Bool PutDesignMultiR PUT" in the routes file of yesod, but get an error:

```
Foundation.hs:46:1:
      No instance for (PathPiece Bool)
      arising from a use of `toPathPiece'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (PathPiece Bool)
```

Does that mean that yesod only supports Int and String, but not Bool?
How to fix it?
Any hints will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: You need to add `instance PathPiece Bool where ...` which must describe way you want to parse a bool from piece of uri path.

Comment: @pxqr Thanks. Where should I add that? In the Foundation.hs?

Comment: I guess so. Yesod book have [this chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/routing-and-handlers#routing-and-handlers_types_of_pieces) explaining routing in yesod.

Comment: @SamvelTruzyan since you answered the question, perhaps you should post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Yesod parses url path parameters using PathPieces instances of the corresponding type. In order to parse a Bool param you need to add `instance PathPiece Bool` which should describe the way you want to parse a bool from a piece of uri path.